# Using my own UIAlertView around an existing library

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using a library called [Chute](http://www.getchute.com) to manage photo selection (from photo library, facebook, etc.).

I'm trying to implement a UIAlertView whenever `selectionCount >= 20`. The problem is, the Chute library handles alertView protocols in its own way, meaning some file is trying to execute

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{}
```

whenever my alert with buttons is displayed, which crashes the app. What should I do to work around the current method? I tried to subclass UIAlertView into a new custom class but I'm not sure where to implement the UIAlertViewDelegate or its protocol. Not sure if this is right either. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't delegate to self but something else?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify ssteinberg?

Comment: If I understand you correctly your UIAlertView's delegate is a class that handles (wrongly) the protocol. Delegate it to something else.

Comment: Ah, that was easier than I thought. I hadn't initially set a delegate, so I didn't know you could actually just do that! Thanks

Comment: I will create an answer then.

Comment: Have you tried calling your method with [self performSelectorOnMainThreath.....]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex:` gets called on UIAlertView's delegate.